# emacs startup says "Invalid face: highlight"

Tags: init-file, faces

When I start up emacs, it prints `Invalid face: highlight` and then exits. This problem happened after I reinstalled Ubuntu 21.04 from scratch.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

- I have tried 26.2 from ubuntu... same problem.
- I have tried downloading and compiling 27.2. Same problem.
- I have tried commenting out every line in my .emacs file. Same problem.
- `emacs -q` has the same problem.
- `emacs -q --debug-init` has the same problem.
- `emacs -Q` brings up an emacs window.

Comment: Is there a backtrace with `--debug-init`? If so, can you post it in some pastebin and link it here?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists with `emacs -q`, and not for `emacs -Q`, then the source is most likely in `site-start.el`. `site-start.el` is sometimes provided by distributions, and you might find it in `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp`, `/etc/emacs/`.

On Ubuntu, running the command `locate site-start.el` from the command line might show you other locations.

Any files in the directory`/etc/emacs/site-start.d/` may be involved too.

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed the problem down to a file in `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp`: `subdirs.el`.

It contains

```
(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)
    (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

instead of the following which is in the source for emacs 27.2:

```
;; In load-path, after this directory should come
;; certain of its subdirectories.  Here we specify them.
(normal-top-level-add-to-load-path '("vc" "url" "textmodes" "progmodes" "play" "org" "nxml" "net" "mh-e" "mail" "leim" "language" "international" "gnus" "eshell" "erc" "emulation" "emacs-lisp" "cedet" "calendar" "calc"  "obsolete"))
;; Local Variables:
;; version-control: never
;; no-byte-compile: t
;; no-update-autoloads: t
;; End:
```